# Camel CxfPayload issue when using namespace with no prefix (xmlns:xmlns)

Tags: namespaces, cxf, apache-camel

I have an issue with using Camel CXF in PAYLOAD mode. I am sending a SOAP request with body having no namespace prefix.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.mycompnay.com/test/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.mycompany.com/test/1/">
    <soap:Body>
        <request>
            <ns1:identifier>TEST</ns1:identifier>
        </request>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I am trying to get the cxf body element as `cxfPayload.getBody().get(0)` which gives me a List of elements.

Now whenever I use a namespace without prefix, the element has a attribute "xmlns:xmlns". And I noticed that this is happening in two places.

1. DefaultCxfBiding.addNamespace(Element, Map)
2. CxfPayload.addNamespace(Element, Map)

And in both the places, "xmlns:" is simply prefixed to nsMap.get(key) without checking if the value is xmlns.

This is causing issues during Schema validation and also if the same CXFPayload is sent to another service (Proxy service patterns), it is causing the Out interceptors to fail as "xmlns:xmlns" is not valid namespace attribute.

Appreciate the help as I am not sure if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bug of camel-cxf, I just created a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7762) for it.